# Iterating through two String[] arrays in parallel?

Tags: java, string, iterator

The following works fine when there is exactly one entry in each array, but otherwise causes an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138, 10.0.0.138"};
String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.0"};

for (String defaultGW: defaultGWs) {
        for (String interfacesNetmask: interfacesNetmasks) {
            SubnetInfo subnetInfo = (new SubnetUtils(defaultGW, interfacesNetmask).getInfo());

            // CIDR signature
            String cidrSignature = subnetInfo.getCidrSignature();
            System.out.println("CIDR Signature: " + cidrSignature);
        }
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse [255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.0]
    at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.toInteger(SubnetUtils.java:287)
    at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.toCidrNotation(SubnetUtils.java:360)
    at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.<init>(SubnetUtils.java:62)
    at GetSubnetInfoJava.main(GetSubnetInfoJava.java:13)
```

How can I loop through a large list of gateways and netmasks in parallel such that on each iteration I can generate a new subnetInfo object?

Comment: Change { "10.0.0.138, 10.0.0.138" } to { "10.0.0.138","10.0.0.138" } same with interfacesNetmasks.

Comment: or may be better use a `Map<String,String>`  to keep your IPs and netmasks attached to them especially if IPs are different etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code actually iterates through *all* interfaceNetmasks for each defaultGW so if you want to go through the arrays in parallel:

- Create *one* for loop based on the number of strings.
- Loop through it pulling a string from each array using the index (the for loop number).
- Keep the rest of your code the same - except fix the quotes in the array items.

  ```
  String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138", "10.0.0.138"};
  String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0"};

  for (int i = 0; i < defaultGWs.length; i++) {

      SubnetInfo subnetInfo = (new SubnetUtils(defaultGWs[i],    interfacesNetmasks[i]).getInfo());

      // CIDR signature
      String cidrSignature = subnetInfo.getCidrSignature();
      System.out.println("CIDR Signature: " + cidrSignature);

  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Beyond the syntax mistake I made this is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138, 10.0.0.138"};
String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.0"};
```

these are the problem. you declare an array of string with only 1 entry each. change it to

```
String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138", "10.0.0.138"};
String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0","255.255.255.0"};
```

now you have 2 arrays with 2 entries ,which you can iterate through properly

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138, 10.0.0.138"};
String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.0"};
```

To:

```
 String[] defaultGWs = {"10.0.0.138", "10.0.0.138"};
 String[] interfacesNetmasks = {"255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0"};
```